# Library for pre OCR image processing framework/library

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I'm looking for a framework/library that will preprocess scanned images and prepare them for further OCR process. For example, it will automatically detect and remove background noise, will improve text contrast etc.

Is there anything available on the market for this purpose?

Comment: On what OS must it run (or, as you ask for a library, with what language must it work)? What is your price limit if it comes to paid software?

Answer (score 1):

The LEADTOOLS Document Imaging library contains various image processing and document clean-up functions. Some of them are specifically designed for OCR pre-processing.  Examples are DotRemoveCommand, DeskewCommand and InvertedPageCommand.
You can try by either downloading the [full SDK trial edition](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=main), or the stand-alone [OCR click-once demo](https://www.leadtools.com/demos/click-once/ocr-advantage).
(Disclaimer: I am an employee of this toolkit’s vendor).

For example, the DotRemoveCommand can be used to automatically remove dots and specks of various sizes, the code will look like this:

```
RasterCodecs codecs = new RasterCodecs(); 
RasterImage image = codecs.Load("image.tif")); 
DotRemoveCommand command = new DotRemoveCommand(DotRemoveCommandFlags.None, 1, 1, 10, 10);  
command.Run(image);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have evaluated "OCR click-once demo", especially "Document clean-up" functionality. Unfortunately, the quality of this process is far from perfect(probably this is my fault but I was unable to find a way to increase the quality).  I'm really sad about it because your software has Java client and works on Linux platform. Right now the best result was achieved with ClearImage Image Processing SDK but the biggest issue to me is that this software works only on Windows.